# Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records with parallel for loop

Tags: c#, sql, task-parallel-library, strongly-typed-dataset

First off let me say that I have done research on this issue and I know how it happens but I don't know what to change in my code to prevent this error. I'm using a parallel foreach loop to quickly go through items and update them in the database. My code is below and I'm using a strongly typed dataset via sql.

```
Parallel.For(0, activeSymbolsCount, j =>
                            {
                                symbol = symbolTable.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(j).Symbol;
                                SymbolInfo symbolClass = new SymbolInfo(symbol, market);
                                StockRating rating = performCalculations(symbolClass);
                                saveToTable(rating);
                            });

public static void saveToTable(StockRating rating)
    {
        if (rating != null)
        {
            string symbol = rating.symbol;
            string market = rating.market;

            using (StockRatingsTableAdapter ratingsAdapter = new StockRatingsTableAdapter())
            using (StockRatingsDataTable ratingsTable = new StockRatingsDataTable())
            {
                ratingsAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
                ratingsAdapter.Adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 1000;
                ratingsAdapter.Fill(ratingsTable);

                var query = from c in ratingsTable
                            where c.Symbol == symbol && c.Market == market
                            select c;

                StockRatingsRow row = query.AsParallel().FirstOrDefault();

                if (row != null)
                {
                    // update the info with the new calculated info
                    row.EstimatedReturn = rating.estimatedReturn;
                    row.LongRating = rating.longRating;
                    row.MediumRating = rating.mediumRating;
                    row.ShortRating = rating.shortRating;
                    row.Risk = rating.risk;
                    row.MarginEnabled = rating.isMarginEnabled;
                }

                StockRatingsDataTable tempRatingsTable = new StockRatingsDataTable();
                tempRatingsTable = (StockRatingsDataTable)ratingsTable.GetChanges();

                if (tempRatingsTable != null)
                {
                    ratingsAdapter.Adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = System.Data.UpdateRowSource.None;
                    ratingsAdapter.Update(tempRatingsTable);
                    tempRatingsTable.Dispose();
                    Console.WriteLine("Stock rating updated for " + rating.symbol + " in the " + rating.market + " market!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the exception when performing an update on this table and the method above is the only time I access any information from this table so that is why I didn't show my other code.

Comment: *What* exception? Show us the error message.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The error message I'm getting is the name of my question above